# submit button only sends the first checkbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a simple project that I want to send information via form and multiple check boxes in asp.net mvc.

This is the view:

[image: View]

And this is the controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Customer customer)
{
  if (customer != null)
  {
     return Content(customer.Name.ToString());
  }
  return Content("empty");
}
```

I know that I am getting a single variable in the controller method but the point is that if I put an `IEnumerable` type like list, array or even `IEnumerable` itself I will receive null value, and if I put a single variable the view page only sends the value of the first checkbox.

Here you can see that I have chosen the B option but the view still returns the A option.

[image: choosing B option]

[image: getting A option]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model binding to a list doesn't play nicely with `foreach`; you need to use `for` instead.

[ASP.NET Wire Format for Model Binding to Arrays, Lists, Collections, Dictionaries - Scott Hanselman's Blog](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/aspnet-wire-format-for-model-binding-to-arrays-lists-collections-dictionaries)

Which means you'll need to change your model to be an indexable list.

```
@model IReadOnlyList<WebApplication2.Models.Customer>
...
@for (int index = 0; index < Model.Count; index++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[index].Name)</td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { Model[index].ID })
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { Model[index].ID })
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { Model[index].ID })
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[index].IsSelected)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[index].ID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.[index].Name)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: thank you mate. i have looked for that goddmn bug for 2 weeks. you solved that. thank u very much